# Using XmlNodeList with several web services call

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, console-application, streamwriter

I am building a console application which calls 3 different web services. The first one call all the project with their projectsIds, projects status and project names.

The first web service get all projectsIDs `GetProjectData()` and the call is correct. I am putting the result into a csv file.

The second call, `GetProjectDetails()` and it provide me a `dataset` of all the projects (with many values into the dataset).

This call contain the projectType (Open or close) where I need to put it next to the GetProjectData() call.

This is the schema from GetProjectDetails dataset call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Table">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ProjectID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="ProjectType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I need to obtain the ProjectType and assign it to my project which is going to show either is open or close.

I have created a method which parse the xml output:

```
public static string parseXML(System.Data.DataSet ds)
{
    string txt = "";
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
    XmlNodeList elements = xml.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/Table");
    foreach (XmlNode elem in elements)
    {
        txt += elem["ProjectType"].InnerText;
        txt += "\n";
    }
    return txt;

}
```

I have another web service call but I am correct with that one because I am having the expected output.

The problem is that I need to extract the projecType into the final result and depending to each project type either is open or close.

Here you have my code.

```
string path = @"c:\testList";
try
{                
string List = "listOfProjects";
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\testList\\{0}.csv", List + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms"));

//This is the call to get all the projects
WS.ProjectData[] pr = db.GetAllProjectData();


using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,Type,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate");

    foreach(WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr.Distinct(new ProjectEqualityComparer()))
    {
        string language = "";
        var userIDs = db.GetList(proj.ProjectID);
        var projectInfo = parseXML(db.GetProjectDetails(language)); //GetProjectDetails require a string into the method

        file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5}",       
        proj.ProjectID,
        proj.ProjectTitle,
        proj.PublishStatus,
        userIDs.Length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
        proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
        proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to output the ProjectType into the final result?
I guess I need to somehow do something with the projectInfo and reference it with the projectIDs so it can know if its the type open or close.

Thanks

Output expected:

```
ProjectID, ProjectTitle, PublishStatus,Type,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate

7bd001b2-991e, "test project", published, open, 01-01-2010, 01-01-2015

4ed00772-541e, "test project 2", expired, Close, 01-01-2010, 01-01-2015
```

What is inside `WS.ProjectData[] pr = db.GetAllProjectData();` is the follows:

```
ProjectID,
ProjectTitle
PublishStatus
ProjectStartDate
ProjectEndDate
```

These are the values that can be exported from `GetAllProjectData()`

The data set also contain ProjectID, so if there's a way to relate the projectId so when its see the same projectID it distribute the ProjectType

I have also noticed, if inside from the parseXML method I pass ProjectID, the first ProjectID from the data set gets into the output on each row (same ProjectID all the time)
Thanks again

Comment: Why are outputting `userIDs.Length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`?  Isn't that where you want to put the `Type`?

Comment: Also, why do you call `var projectInfo = parseXML(db.GetProjectDetails(language));` inside the loop?  You're just passing a constant empty string.

Comment: @dbc I need userID and type. userId comes from GetList() web service and type are coming from GetProjectDetails() web service, that's why I need both results

Comment: @dbc GetPtojectDetails() need as a parameters a string, and when I was using SOAPUI, that string can be empty. I putted inside the loop because I need all the output with the same relation (projectID), thanks

Comment: But you're not passing the `projectID` to `db.GetProjectDetails(language)`, you're passing an empty string.

Comment: @dbc I was thinking about that, but since I saw in SOAPUI that the require parameter is string language and not projectID. I tried to pass proj.ProjectID but I get an error saying (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less that the size of the collection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90062/discussion-between-a-arancibia-and-dbc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're bothering to convert your `DataSet` to XML, then parse the XML.  The `DataSet` can be queried and iterated through directly.

Given the schema you have shown for your `DataSet`, to get a comma separated list of all `ProjectType` values, do:

```
using System.Data; // For System.Data.DataTableExtensions

    var ds = db.GetProjectDetails(language);
    var projectInfo = string.Join(",", ds.Tables["Table"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["ProjectType"].ToString()).ToArray());
```

Given a `string projectId` value, to find its corresponding `ProjectType`, you can use [`DataTable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    string projectId = proj.ProjectID.ToString();
    var ds = db.GetProjectDetails(language);
    var type = var type = ds.Tables["Table"].Select("ProjectId = '" + projectId + "'").Select(r => r["ProjectType"]).SingleOrDefault();
    // Output the type to the file with the rest of the data.
```

Or, do it directly with a Linq [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418.aspx) filter:

```
using System.Data; // For System.Data.DataTableExtensions

    string projectId = proj.ProjectID.ToString();
    var ds = db.GetProjectDetails(language);
    var type = ds.Tables["Table"].AsEnumerable().Where(r => projectId.Equals(r["ProjectId"])).Select(r => r["ProjectType"]).SingleOrDefault();
    // Output the type to the file with the rest of the data.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Where I need to place the options you provide me? into the public static string parseXML(System.Data.DataSet ds) method?. When I try it to put it there I get the error (Not all code paths return a value)

Comment: I made the changes and I getting as an error Sequence contains more than one element. Thanks for all the help and support!

Comment: @Aarancibia - that would mean there is more than one row in the `DataSet` for a given project ID.  What do you want to do in that case?  Also, are you using the `Select` or the `Where` option?

Comment: I worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks a lot!!! you saved my life!!! thanks!!! I appreciated it!!

Answer (score 0):

I would have done `parseXml` method so:

```
static List<string> parseXml(DataSet ds)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        list.Add(row["ProjectType"].ToString());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Then we make something like:

```
int counter = 0;

foreach(WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr.Distinct(new ProjectEqualityComparer()))
{
    // your code here

    var projectInfo = parseXml(ds);

    file.WriteLine("{0},{1}, ... ",
    proj.ProjectID,
    projectInfo[counter],
    // ...
    );

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I only have a problem when I do what you suggested me in the line var projectInfo = parseXml(ds); its says ds not exist in the current context

Comment: Pay attention upper/lower letter case. I renamed method `parseXML` to `parseXml` to conform generally accepted naming conventions.

Comment: sorry I have another question. It work but the output is not putting the ProjectType according to each projectID, its given to each project the same ProjectType

Comment: @Aarancibia - Then we need more info. [Edit] question and show the data contained in `WS.ProjectData [] pr`.

Comment: I have edited the question, at the end there's more details. Thanks again